# Scikit-learn can't load "pairwise_fast.so" and "arrayfuncs.so" dynamic library in centos7

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
I install scikit-learn successfully.
Now try to using " nosetests -v sklearn" validation sklearn. 
Unfortunately, the console printed some error message as below:

Failure: ImportError (/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise_fast.so: undefined symbol: dasum_) ... ERROR
Failure: ImportError (/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/arrayfuncs.so: undefined symbol: drot_) ... ERROR

Seems Can't to load function some funciont from library "pairwise_fast.so" and "pairwise_fast.so".

System environment as below:
    CentOS 7.1.1503
    python(2.7.5)
    numpy (1.10.1)
    scipy (0.16.1)
    scikit-learn (0.15.0)

Greatly appreciated, hope someone help me to solve this problem!



=========================
[root]# ldd /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise_fast.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffbbffe000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1113bcf00``0)
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f1113808000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f11135ec000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f111322b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1113026000)
    libutil.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libutil.so.1
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

[root]# strings pairwise_fast.so | grep dasum_
    dasum_
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `ldd /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise_fast.so`?

Comment: I updated the dynamic library information.

Comment: I think `pairwise_fast.so` should be linked against `blas`. I cannot say for sure, though. I would try to to reinstall scikit-learn and see if that already helps.

Comment: I have tried for many times installation, seems to be not to take effect.I will try to find the right version for scikit-learn on centos7. I will continue to update if any new discovery.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I ran into a similar problem in Redhat. @cel is correct, the library should be linked against `blas` or `atlas` libraries, which are normally installed system-wide. The only way to force this seems to be downloading the source from https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn and running a manual installation. This allows you to fine-tune the configuration.